# How to stop content going out of website?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

As you can see in the snippet bellow. I am trying to fit all the content but it is going out on the website, especially on the small devices (iphone x for example), parts of the content are not there. Any idea how to fix this? Thanks for any help as I dont know how to do this but presumebly something with flexbox

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;padding: 0;margin: 0;}
.row{
    display: flex;
    
 
}
img{
    width:450px;
    height:350px;
    display: block;
    
}
.container{
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   align-items: center;
   margin: auto;
    margin-top:50px;
    
}
.column1{
    margin-top: -30px;
    margin-right: 7%;
    position:relative;
    height: 0%;
}
.column2{
    margin-left: 6%;
   margin-top: 70px;
    position:relative;
}
.text h1{
    width:450px;
    
}
.text h1{
    font-family: muli, sans-serif;
    font-size: 3.5rem;
    font-weight:100;
}
.column2 .cover,.column1 .cover{
    bottom:0px;
    position:absolute;
    opacity: 0.8;
    font-family: muli, sans-serif;
    font-weight:500;
    width: 100%;
    height:50px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items: center;
    color:white;
    
}

.dark{
background-color: #0E4C92;
}
.light{
    background-color: #00B5FD; 
}
.icon{
    position:absolute;
    right:-60px;
    top:8%;
    width:120px;
    height:120px;
    border-radius:50%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px 1px gray;
}
@media (max-width: 960px) {
    .row {
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        margin-top:10%;
        margin-bottom: 15%;
        justify-content: center;
        
        
        
    }
    .column1,.column2{
        margin-left: 0%;
        margin-right: 0%;
        
        
    }
  
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/dsl6sbt.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row1 row">
        <div class="column1 text">
            <h1>Solutions for<br> medical<br> applications</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="column2">
            <img class="icon" src ="Datový zdroj 2.svg" alt="My Happy SVG"/>
            <img src="Fluids.jpg" alt=""></img>
            <div class="cover light"><h2>Fluids</h2></div>
        </div>
       
      </div>  
    
      <div class="row2 row">
            <div class="column1">
                <img class="icon" src ="Datový zdroj 5.svg" alt="My Happy SVG"/>
                <img src="medical.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="cover light"><h2>Medical device</h2></div>
            </div>
            <div class="column2">
                <img class="icon" src ="Datový zdroj 6.svg" alt="My Happy SVG"/>        
                <img src="SurgicalTools.jpg" alt=""> 
                <div class="cover dark"><h2>Surgical tools and instruments</h2></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    
      <div class="row3 row">
            <div class="column1">
                <img class="icon" src ="Datový zdroj 1.svg" alt="My Happy SVG"/>
                <img src="DrugDevice.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="cover dark"><h2>Drug delivery device</h2></div>
            </div>
            <div class="column2">
                <img class="icon" src ="Datový zdroj 1.svg" alt="My Happy SVG"/>
                <img src="Packaging.jpg" alt=""> 
                <div class="cover light"><h2>Packaging</h2></div>       
            </div>
      </div>
    
      <div class="row4 row">
            <div class="column1">
                <img class="icon" src ="Datový zdroj 3.svg" alt="My Happy SVG"/>
                <img src="HomeCare.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="cover light"><h2>Home care</h2></div>
            </div>
            <div class="column2">
                <img class="icon" src ="Datový zdroj 4.svg" alt="My Happy SVG"/>
                <img src="Labware.jpg" alt=""> 
                <div class="cover dark"><h2>Labware</h2></div>       
            </div>
      </div>
</div> 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Absolute positioning is troublesome and should be used sparingly. It rarely has a place in flex layouts. I'd start with that.

Comment: so how to handle it differently?

Comment: Hard to say without knowing what your goals are. You haven't been very specific on that. Hard-coded image sizes and negative margins raise some questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can accomplish what you are looking for by adding some media queries and adjusting the width and height of the images and icons. I edited your code for a 320px screen, but you can also add one for 768px screens, etc. I also targeted your bigger images more specifically as just using `img` in your CSS rule, those properties were also affecting your icon images at times.

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;padding: 0;margin: 0;}
.row{
    display: flex;
    
 
}
img[src$="jpg"]{
    width:450px;
    height:350px;
    display: block;
}
.container{
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   align-items: center;
   margin: auto;
    margin-top:50px;
    
}
.column1{
    margin-top: -30px;
    margin-right: 7%;
    position:relative;
    height: 0%;
}
.column2{
    margin-left: 6%;
   margin-top: 70px;
    position:relative;
}
.text h1{
    width:450px;
    
}
.text h1{
    font-family: muli, sans-serif;
    font-size: 3.5rem;
    font-weight:100;
}
.column2 .cover,.column1 .cover{
    bottom:0px;
    position:absolute;
    opacity: 0.8;
    font-family: muli, sans-serif;
    font-weight:500;
    width: 100%;
    height:50px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items: center;
    color:white;
    
}

.dark{
background-color: #0E4C92;
}
.light{
    background-color: #00B5FD; 
}
.icon{
    position:absolute;
    right:-60px;
    top:8%;
    width:120px;
    height:120px;
    border-radius:50%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px 1px gray;
}

@media (max-width: 475px){
  .text h1 {
    width: 90%;
  }
  .icon {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    right: -30px
  }
  img[src$="jpg"]{
    width:250px;
    height:250px;
    display: block;
}
}
@media (max-width: 960px) {
    .row {
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        margin-top:10%;
        margin-bottom: 15%;
        justify-content: center;
        
                
    }
    .column1,.column2{
        margin-left: 0%;
        margin-right: 0%;
        
        
    }
  
  }
```

```html
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row1 row">
        <div class="column1 text">
            <h1>Solutions for<br> medical<br> applications</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="column2">
            <img class="icon" src ="Datový zdroj 2.svg" alt="My Happy SVG"/>
            <img src="Fluids.jpg" alt=""></img>
            <div class="cover light"><h2>Fluids</h2></div>
        </div>
       
      </div>  
    
      <div class="row2 row">
            <div class="column1">
                <img class="icon" src ="Datový zdroj 5.svg" alt="My Happy SVG"/>
                <img src="medical.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="cover light"><h2>Medical device</h2></div>
            </div>
            <div class="column2">
                <img class="icon" src ="Datový zdroj 6.svg" alt="My Happy SVG"/>        
                <img src="SurgicalTools.jpg" alt=""> 
                <div class="cover dark"><h2>Surgical tools and instruments</h2></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    
      <div class="row3 row">
            <div class="column1">
                <img class="icon" src ="Datový zdroj 1.svg" alt="My Happy SVG"/>
                <img src="DrugDevice.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="cover dark"><h2>Drug delivery device</h2></div>
            </div>
            <div class="column2">
                <img class="icon" src ="Datový zdroj 1.svg" alt="My Happy SVG"/>
                <img src="Packaging.jpg" alt=""> 
                <div class="cover light"><h2>Packaging</h2></div>       
            </div>
      </div>
    
      <div class="row4 row">
            <div class="column1">
                <img class="icon" src ="Datový zdroj 3.svg" alt="My Happy SVG"/>
                <img src="HomeCare.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="cover light"><h2>Home care</h2></div>
            </div>
            <div class="column2">
                <img class="icon" src ="Datový zdroj 4.svg" alt="My Happy SVG"/>
                <img src="Labware.jpg" alt=""> 
                <div class="cover dark"><h2>Labware</h2></div>       
            </div>
      </div>
</div> 
 
</body>
```